# Form-Data array not being deserialized to request dto

Tags: json, kendo-ui, servicestack, servicestack-text

I'm trying to do filtering function for KendoUI Grid.

Kendo sends data as form-data:

```
take:20
skip:0
page:1
pageSize:20
filter[filters][0][operator]:eq
filter[filters][0][value]:abc
filter[filters][0][field]:No
filter[logic]:and
```

I tried to deserialize it using dto:

```
public class FilteringRule
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class FilteringInfo
{
    public string Logic { get; set; }
    public FilteringRule[] Filters { get; set; }
}

public class FilteredQuery
{
    FilteringInfo Filter { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

but deserialization fails:

```
'filter[filters][0][operator]' does not exist on type 'FilteredQuery'
'filter[filters][0][value]' does not exist on type 'FilteredQuery'
'filter[filters][0][field]' does not exist on type 'FilteredQuery'
'filter[logic]' does not exist on type 'FilteredQuery'
```

How to make this work? When I manually send json instead of form-data it works.

Can kendo send json? Setting contentType: "application/json" in datasource doesn't help. Kendo still sends data as form-data, servicestack throws error: "unable to bind request".

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding why not using DataSourceRequest

Answer (score 1):

ServiceStack allows [sending complex objects via QueryStrings](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string) using the lightweight JSV Syntax which from your example would look something like:

```
?filter={filters:[{operator:eq,value:abc,field:no}],{logic:and}}
```

But since Kendo is unlikely to support this syntax, you would be better off sending JSON if it supports it which would naturally map to your DTOs.